# How to select in MySQL with data |xx|xx|xx|

Tags: mysql

I want ask:

I have two tables `employee` with fields `ID`, `Fullname`, `email`... and table `task` with fields `name_task`, `list_employee`...

With field `list_employee` I saved with data example `|1509|1510|1511|`,

Now I want select list employee from field `list_employee`

Help me!

Thanks

Comment: This kind of data violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), so if you can restructure this into a proper relational form that would be a *lot* better.

Comment: Your data is in poor shape, but I would say that if you don't at least show us your expected output then you do not merit an answer.

Comment: storing data that way is a bad idea, sorry. You will have all sorts of complex query issues because of that data

Answer (score 1):

The following query might be along the lines of what you have in mind:

```
SELECT t.*, e.*
FROM task t
INNER JOIN employee e
    ON t.list_employee LIKE CONCAT('%|', e.ID, '|%')
-- WHERE t.name_task = 'some task'
```

This would match a given task record and its pipe separated list of employees with every matching record from the `employee` table.  Note that as all the above comments say, it is bad practice to store unnormalized data in this way.  A much better way to persist tasks and their associated employees would be something like this:

```
name_task | ID
cleaning  | 1509
cleaning  | 1510
cleaning  | 1511
washing   | 1001
...
```

This makes working with your data much easier, as the database no longer has to sift out employees from strings.